# Changing Access Database Field Value Based on Condition of Other Fields

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to change the value of one field based on another field in an Access Database.

Let's say I have 4 fields A, B, C and D. If the value of A is negative, the value of cell D should be some calculated value based on fields B, C and the last value (if I am checking row 500, I will also be needing the value for row 499) of field D itself. Is there a query command to do this type of operation easily or do I need to run loops? The database will have around million inputs.

Thanks in advance,

As I do not have much experience, I am not much aware to how to solve this.

Comment: You want a calculation based on data in another record? That is not easy to do, especially in Access. Review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord.  Query based on a million-record dataset will likely perform very slowly. Just calculating in query does not save to table. Usually bad design to save calculated (dependent) data.

Comment: Sidenote: Access table does not have 'cells' it has fields. Cell is a spreadsheet term.

Comment: be specific, provide an easily reproducible example of what you want.  see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  This could be as simple as making D a calculated field or require complex sql based on table structures and relationships

Comment: Welcome bladeyus! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are coming from Excel. Access tables are a little bit different. There is no defined order of records (=rows) therefore each record is alone and knows nothing about the record before or next. This makes it difficult the calculate.
Best way would be to use VBA to create a recordset and move through each record to check if you have to manipulate the data.
In case that you can identify the previous record needed for calculation e. g. by ID or specific data, then you could access the data with a DLOOKUP (also in a query) - but that is a very slow function and your query can run long. Check if you can reduce the number of records to process to avoid long process time.